# Pass JS variable to hidden input

Tags: javascript

I want to pass "longitude,latitude" in my hidden input's value field. I tried different approaches but I'm not getting any values filled. Here's the code that I have:

```
<form class="myForm" action="includes/teste.php" method="POST" id="form-id">
<input name="myField" type="hidden" id="myField" class="myField" value="" />
</form>

<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else
{
alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
}
function showPosition(pos){
//document.write("Latitude: "+pos.coords.latitude+" Longitude: "+pos.coords.longitude);
//document.getElementById("hidden1").value = "Latitude: "+pos.coords.latitude+" Longitude: "+pos.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById('myField').value = (pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude);

}



document.getElementById("form-id").submit()
</script>
```

I'll edit it back.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Your hidden input doesn't have a name, so it won't be sent to the server when you submit the form.

Comment: How do you know that the hidden field is not getting a value?

Comment: Added a name, still no value in the source code.

Comment: I check the source code. Uhmm... should I check with $_POST instead?

Comment: If you are using view source, it wouldn't show because it is updated after loading. You should inspect the element.

Comment: @stepanian please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, I tested and indeed you're right :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using view source, it wouldn't show because it is updated after loading. You should inspect the element.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69540/discussion-on-answer-by-stepanian-pass-js-variable-to-hidden-input).

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, may be you have to check with function passing parameter.

If your using some post method in getting result's,then use inspect element in browser. 
If you are using Firefox go for [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score -1):

A value should be a string and a string starts with quotes.

In other news,  script language=  ,  document.write and navigator.geolocation sure is an interesting mix.  Kind of like a javascript hall of fame through the ages